# How to login with Cypress against Keycloak running on a different host

Tags: angular, cypress, keycloak, e2e-testing

I am using keycloak (21) to manage the login procedure for an angular (14) application and the keycloak-angular library to manage the connection between the application and keycloak.
Keycloak is running on a different host and I redirect to the keycloak login page to fill in credentials.
The problem comes up when I try to test login in an e2e context using Cypress (13). The app starts locally (localhost), the login part is redirected to keycloak url and at this point cypress is not able to find the page my app is redirecting to.

After some research I found out that cy.origin should do the trick and I tried the following code:

```
cy.origin(thirdPartyServerUrl, {args: {username, password}}, ({username, password}) => {
cy.get('[id=username]').click().type(username);
cy.get('[id=password]').click().type(password);
cy.get('#kc-login').click();
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not find the keycloak login page.

Additional info:

- the login procedure works fine if the app starts on the same host as keycloak, but I need to get the setup running with different hosts too.
- the keycloak-angular lib is using an iFrame which from what I read might cause problems with Cypress
- I managed to login via KC API but didn't find a way to "tell" the browser that I'm already logged in

Any advice would be highly appreciated, should you have any question please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The origin command is the correct way to approach, presuming `thirdPartyServerUrl` is actually serving the form you are filling. If the app doesn't take you there automatically, you can explicitly visit, something like this

```js
cy.origin(thirdPartyServerUrl, {args: {username, password}}, ({username, password}) => {

  cy.visit('/home')     // url redirects to login form on thirdPartyServerUrl

  cy.get('[id=username]').click().type(username);
  cy.get('[id=password]').click().type(password);
  cy.get('#kc-login').click();
})
```

You probably want to add a `cy.session()` command to keep the credentials across multiple tests

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
  const args = { username, password }
  cy.session(args, () => {
    cy.origin(thirdPartyServerUrl, {args}, ({username, password}) => {
      cy.visit('/home')
      cy.get('[id=username]').type(username)
      cy.get('[id=password]').type(password)
      cy.get('#kc-login').click()
    })
  })
  cy.url().should('contain', '/home')     // redirects back here after login
})

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.login(username, password)
})

it('tests as logged-in user', () => {
  ...
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The problem is keycloak host url has a parameter called "redirect_uri" and by default it points to keycloak host. In order to be redirected to localhost I have to change the url.
This url contains multiple parameters and I am not sure how I could modify only the "redirect_uri".

Comment: Ideally the redirects are hidden from the user, and ideally from the e2e test also. I would expect you visit `/home` which takes you to `/login` which takes you back to `/home` after submitting credentials.

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect that sequence.

Comment: Indeed visiting "/home" should go to keycloak "/login" page and if the login is successful back to "/home". 
However when I try to visit localhost, I see this log in cypress and the page is blank:
` visit/frontend
(uncaught exception)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'contentWindow') 
(uncaught exception)SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`